# "that" or "this"

Tags: pronouns, this-that

I know a trivial difference of "that" and "this" uses. Such as the difference between "this chair" and "that chair".
But I don't understand one case. When one person is coming into a room and another has been doing something. And the first one asks him "Why are you doing that?". I heard about the same questions with "that" in many analogous situations in different movies. And the main question is why "that", not "this". I think that "this" more fits here, because a situation is in front of an asking person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the action may be taking place in front of the person asking the question, it is nevertheless taking place at a distance, both physically and situationally. It's the OTHER person who is performing the action, and so it's taking place 'over there', in a different personal space. *Why are you doing **this***, on the other hand, would often refer to an action that affects both parties.

Answer (score 4):

You could use either word in that context, although "that" sounds much more natural to me.  And the meaning is slightly different.

> Why are you doing that?

Would be taken to mean "Why are you doing that specific thing that you are doing?"

> Why are you doing this?

Would be taken in a more general sense, as if the thing the person is doing is affecting an entire situation.

Let me illustrate with an example.

Suppose a wife walks in to find her husband with another woman.  If she says *Why are you doing that?* it would be taken to mean "Why are doing those things with that woman?"  Whereas if she says *Why are you doing this?* she probably means "Why are you acting this way, disregarding my feelings, and putting our entire marriage at risk?"